# How to add stroke to a curve only in the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I tried multiple values but I can't figure it out to add stroke only to the bottom.

```css
.curveDownColor{
        display: inline;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top:25px;
        z-index: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 50,50,100
    }
```

```html
<svg class='curveDownColor' height='60' preserveAspectRatio='none' style=' fill:#000; stroke:#ff742c; stroke-width:3;' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <path d='M0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z'/>
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the strokedasharray and the offset, I found that these values work for a stroke at the bottom:

```
stroke-dasharray: 190;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
```

```css
.curveDownColor{
        display: inline;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top:25px;
        z-index: 0;
        stroke-dasharray:190;
        stroke-dashoffset:0;
    }
```

```html
<svg class='curveDownColor' height='60' preserveAspectRatio='none' style=' fill:#000; stroke:#ff742c; stroke-width:3;' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <path d='M0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z'/>
        </svg>
```